# How to treat questions that are deleted by the OP

Tags: discussion

I am looking at [*Executing a perl script with ProcessBuilder*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863858/executing-a-perl-script-with-processbuilder) whose author has deleted his post and scurried away, either because he is embarrassed to have asked a question with such a simple answer, or because he thinks the page is no longer of any use to him, and he doesn't imagine the wider impact.

I think this particular question warrants undeleting, and I have voted accordingly. But it seems strange that highly-experienced people can single-handedly suspend a question while it takes (I think) three votes to resurrect a question after the OP has deleted it.

Deleted questions aren't generally on most answerers' radar, and a deleted question is unlikely to be seen by anyone doing an ordinary daily scan.

This is wrong. The Stack Overflow rules, as they are, unreasonably favour very poor requests that most of the senior subscribers would prefer to be prohibited, while intelligent questions from diffident people may be answered and deleted without any continued value to anyone who would search the site.

I'm not sure what the solution may be, but it would seem obvious to disallow posters from deleting their questions. Dreadful questions will soon be vote-bombed enough to vanish immediately or be vacuumed by Roomba. And after all, a "deleted" question never goes away, but simply has different privileges applied to it.

What is a better solution?

Comment: I believe there are already restrictions in place to prevent people from deleting their own questions when they have upvoted answers.

Comment: If you believe question is good enough to exist on the site I think asking again (potentially clarified version) and self-answering (potentially as CW if you are not author of the original answer) sounds like very low cost solution.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: It is very common for clarification and potential answers to be posted as comments. In the case that I linked the OP posted a *"duh I just had to do X"* comment and deleted their question. That safeguard could never come into effect.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I thought the same thing and experimentally posted a duplicate of a question that I thought shouldn't have been deleted. I was villified for it. I don't think that's the answer. As I said, I think inexperienced posters should be unable to demote their own posts. The community is smart enough to do it for them if it's that dreadful, and it may be a useful reminder that they're writing what is essentially a wiki page rather than a forum request.

Comment: Were you vilified because someone recognized it as a duplicate of the deleted post, because the question had an obvious answer, or simply because it was a self-answered Q&A.

Comment: @BSMP: I declared it to be a copy of a previous post, and the comments made it clear that that was the reason. **Álexei's** suggestion isn't viable unless one were to make every effort to disguise the fact that the post was a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

Personally (and since this also comes within my stomping grounds of the Java tag), I don't see much reason to bring this back.

- [This is, beyond a shadow of a doubt, a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13991007/1079354)  Executing external programs in Java is an old technique, and I'd be stunned if one couldn't find resources like this either here on Stack Overflow or elsewhere on the internet.
- The question appears to be turning colors.  Here's a comment from the OP which leads me to believe that this isn't going to remain the same question:

  > Excuse me, it seems that I have to add `waitFor()`. The perl script is executed by the `pb.start` but it returns to the java and it seems that the perl script is running in background. As I added `int exitCode = p.waitFor();` it says `unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

  I can't trust that the OP is going to keep their question on how to execute an external app without it turning into a, "How do I deal with checked exceptions?"-question.
- The problem doesn't really lie in their Java code; it *likely* lies in their Perl.  The real problem here is that **they're not asking a question about Perl.**  They're asking a question about external executable interop (which just so happens to be Perl) in Java.

I really don't see a reason for this to come back.  I don't see any value here that hasn't been already covered elsewhere.  If it were resurrected, I'd very likely close it as a dupe at *best*.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, but this doesn't answer my question in general. It isn't hard to imagine a perfectly valid question to which none of these exceptions, or any others, apply, but where the OP has got his answer, deleted the question, and vanished.

Comment: You may take issue with the fact that the question is deleted, but I take issue with the question.  You haven't provided an argument to justify why it should be undeleted; just that you think it's wrong that the OP deleted it. I've provided evidence to show that it's better off deleted.

Comment: I understand that. I failed to recognise the problems with the question that you raise, probably because my knowledge of Java is very limited, and I think I broadly agree with you. However, it isn't hard to imagine a perfectly valid question that an inexperienced user has deleted after resolving his own situation, without realising that Stack Overflow exists primarily as a resource for other people to benefit from solutions to situations similar to their own. It is a solution to these deletions that I am seeking,but I don't have any better example to offer you.

Comment: Fair, but that problem is as old as allowing users to delete their own questions.  Over time I've accepted that those users don't need to be here, and there are checks in the system to punish users who delete questions with answers anyway. Further, a good answer will get upvoted and the OP *can't* then delete their question.  It's really not that big of a deal.